# how to detect and eliminate suspicious activity on the computer

Tags: windows-7, networking, hibernate, virus-removal, malware-detection

I have a particularly weird problem on my Windows 7 desktop pc running on an Intel CPU with a Gigabyte motherboard and CorsAir smps. Here are a few observations which might be connected to the bigger problem.

I hibernate my computer every night and confirm that the power on the CPU has indeed been turned off. The computer is still connected to the mains, which means I need to only press the power button to start it up. When I get up in the morning, the computer is back on. This happens automatically only in the night. I tested this by hibernating it in the morning and it did not switch back on all day. I am not sure if my computer has wake on lan. This has been going on for over almost 6 months now. I just thought of it as some inconvenience and just pulled out the plug eventually.

Recently I found myself infected with the IStartSurf virus which keeps attaching itself to my browzers. I tried to fix this by running the latest free versions of MalwareBytes, SpyHunter, AVG and AVAST. AVG and AVAST bought up some Trojans and worms which I killed. It did not detect istartsurf. MalwareBytes and SpyHunter did and I killed it with that. Still no effect after a restart.

Another thing is I noticed my bandwidth getting used up without me doing anything on the network. I used Networx to check the bandwidth used and I see about 5GB of outgoing data within a span of 2 hours today morning.

I tried to use Netstat to see what outgoing connections are there and I couldnt understand much from all that gibberish. I want to be flagged when any hidden or spyware or ransomware application is occupying memory space or attempting to connect to some resource outside for uploading or downloading data and also rid my pc of all the viruses. Is a clean reinstall the only option?

Comment: If you want to be absolutely 100% sure that the system is free from all rootkits and the like then a clean install is the only way. Just remember to install good anti-malware apps and secure your system to prevent it from being reinfected.

Comment: an example of good anti-malware apps would be?

Comment: You can get lots of great suggestions over at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com :)